# res.locals won't update, keeps displaying the old value

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

In my main app.js file I have this piece of code:

```
app.use(function (req, res, next){
    res.locals.currentUser = req.user;
    next(); 
});
```

... which as you can see serves to get the user info from the passport. And it does it's job... that is until it is used more than once. Whenever I login as a user, and I hit any other routes, that should trigger the res.locals.currentUser to update... but it doesn't. It stays on the old value.. And I can't for the life of me figure out why. I've read the documentation and triple checked everything. Nothing seems to be out of order.

[HERE](https://github.com/AleksandarColovic/YelpCampRepository) is all of the code.

Most important files:

- [Main file](https://github.com/AleksandarColovic/YelpCampRepository/blob/master/app.js)
- [Header](https://github.com/AleksandarColovic/YelpCampRepository/blob/master/views/partials/header.ejs)
- [Index Page](https://github.com/AleksandarColovic/YelpCampRepository/blob/master/views/campgrounds/index.ejs)

***IMPORTANT NOTE***: Every other instance of trying to get the user from passport by directly asking for it from passport works like a charm. Example is the line 58 in the main file:

```
res.render("campgrounds/index", {campgrounds: campgrounds, user1: req.user});
```

,that corresponds to lines 7-11 from the index page:

```
<% if(!user1) { %>
     <h1> Welcome to YelpCamp! </h1>
<% } else { %>
     <h1> <%= user1.username %>, Welcome to YelpCamp! </h1>
<% } %>
```

It returns the user data correctly every time. Any ideas why this is reacting this way? Thanks.

Comment: Try to move your code `app.use(...)` bellow passport. Somewhere bellow line 42 in app.js I believe that the reg.user is populated by either session or passport so having app.use above that doesn't make sense to me. But i'm  no longer using express  and don't remember exactly.

Comment: @Molda You were right. Idk how I missed out on such a simple thing. It works now, thanks.